# Titanium Studio and VirtualBox Android x86

Tags: installation, titanium, virtualbox, android-x86

Step by step: 0) Install Appcelerator Titanium Studio.
1) Install Oracle VirtualBox.

2) Download and Install Android x86 VM. Instructions (Russian) here http://habrahabr.ru/post/119931/

3) Run and configure Android x86 (configure means that you should have 2 ethernet adapters and your Android x86 Virtual Machine(VM) must have an IP (for example 192.168.56.101))

3.5) try to ping your VM. Everithing should works just fine.

4) Run you Titanium studio and create an new project.

5) Run command line and from %Android SDK%/platform-tools/ directory perform operation

```
"adb connect  192.168.56.101".
```

it has to connect to VM successfully  on port 5555.

Note: IF you not did this your Titanium Studio will log something like this

```
    [DEBUG] ...\AndroidSDK\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server
    [INFO] Titanium SDK version: 2.1.4 (11/09/12 12:46 51f2c64)
    [DEBUG] Waiting for device to be ready ...
    [TRACE] adb devices returned 0 devices/emulators
    [TRACE] adb devices returned 0 devices/emulators
    [TRACE] adb devices returned 0 devices/emulators
```

6) Try to install your Titanium Application on the DEVICE. As a platform i select Android 4.0.3 [x86]

6.5) Titanium studio would do a lot of work and it ends with:

```
    [DEBUG] Waiting for device to be ready ...
    [TRACE] adb devices returned 1 devices/emulators
    [DEBUG] Device connected... (waited 0 seconds)
    [DEBUG] waited 0.015000 seconds on emulator to get ready
    [INFO] Installing application on device
```

7) Titanium successfully found the and have connected to the device? compiled all of the resources and trying to install your application to the device with this:

```
"C:\!Development\AndroidSDK\platform-tools\adb.exe -d install -r C:\!Development\Titanium\china\build\android\bin\app.apk"
```

But there is not matter how much time you will wait it won't install.

What is the problem? What i did wrong?

Comment: how long did you wait? using the usual emulator i sometimes hav to wait more than 5 minutes? Did you try to manually install application?

Comment: yes i've tried manually install application with cmd by performing commands: "adb connect 192.168.56.101" and "adb install -r c:\.....\app.apk" and everything works fine. I've been waiting for 30 minutes and nothing happens. I think it could be because there is an additional param "-d" that is used by Titanium when it is installing application on the device. "-d" - device connected on USB. If it is the problem than how can i change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make corrections to the file:

```
%HOME%\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.0.2.GA\android\builder.py
```

according to the screenshots in [this article](http://reinraus.ru/wordpress/nastraivaem-titanium-studio-dlya-zapuska-prilozhenij-v-android-x86/) (Russian).

Answer (score 0):

Can't this help? 
It seems that you need to use adbhost
http://code.google.com/p/android-on-freerunner/wiki/AndroidDebugBridge

Here is the manual from xda to make it through wifi
[How can I connect to Android with ADB over TCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp)

Comment: It seems to me that that articles are about how to connect Android OS to my host OS. It would be useful for those who have a problem with that. I can connect and i can install my applications on my Android-x86 VM, if i make it manually, but what i can't do is to install my application from Titanium Studio. Titanium connects to the "device"(my Android VM), compiling all the resources, but when it tries to install there is nothing happens. I was waiting for an hour and nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Link in ReinRaus 's post is down, i wanted to share the solution with you guys:

Get to **%APPDATA%/Titanium/mobilesdk/win32/3.1.3.GA/android** and open up **builder.py**
(Note: Replace 3.1.3.GA with your Version)

At around line #2601 you find:

```
device_args = ['-d']
# We have to be careful here because Windows can't handle an empty argument
# on the command line, so if a device serial number is not passed in, but
# a debugger_host (the argument after device serial number) _is_ passed in,
# to Windows it just looks like a serial number is passed in (the debugger_host
# argument shifts left to take over the empty argument.)
```

This is the line which causes the Install Script to force USBDebug mode, as seen in the Log while deploying:

```
[DEBUG] XX/sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe -d shell ls /data/app/xx.yyy.zzz*.apk
```

Change the args to **['-a']**. This will stop forcing USB Devices only and you should be fine